# installer creation - cross platform

Tags: windows, macos, installation, cross-platform, izpack

I've got to create an installer to work on both Win and Mac OSX.

The installer needs to determine a particular location to install the files. ie it needs to search for the path of a particular installed application (there could be multiple versions of this application installed), and then let the user (via a dialogue) to choose which path to install the files.

Once the user has chosen which path to install at, the installer also needs to back up (zip up ) some files inside that directory, before installing the files.

I'm wondering if there is a straight forward way of doing this on win/mac? I'm not particularly worried about having the ability to uninstall etc. Just need to get the files installed where they should be.

I've looked at IzUnpack and a few others, but struggling to see whether they are applicable to me.

Cheers

Ke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a framework, which does that. But you could write your own installer i.e. in Java, which should run on most Windows and Mac installations, because most of them already have Java installed.

Also note, that on Mac OSX, it is common, that an application is just a folder with the suffix .app and runs independent of where it is located, so installation is basically just drag-and-dropping this .app-folder (which is shown as a single file in finder) in the user/system's Applications folder.

Comment: Yes, I think your answer is right. However, there are two apps already installed. My app basically copies files into these two already installed apps (and does some processing, zipping up of files). It seems such a chore to find out things like "already installed app locations" etc to make an installer for this

Comment: Java isn't part of the default OS X install any more. OS X will offer to download & install it when you try to open a Java app, but that doesn't make for a very nice user experience...